# selecting JSONPath Query attributes

Tags: json, jsonpath

complete noob, trying to rearrange someone elses list..

hes structured it like this

```
[{
        "name": "noot",
        "things": [{
                "stuff": "a",
                "id": 1,
                "otherid": 11
            },
            {
                "stuff": "b",
                "id": 2,
                "otherid": 22
            },
            {
                "stuff": "c",
                "id": 3,
                "otherid": 33
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "doot",
        "things": [{
                "stuff": "a",
                "id": 1,
                "otherid": 111
            },
            {
                "stuff": "b",
                "id": 2,
                "otherid": 222
            },
            {
                "stuff": "c",
                "id": 3,
                "otherid": 333
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and i want to get a result of

```
noot
11
22
33
doot
111
222
333
```

(name, otherid)

** edit ** i have a list, i was gonna just work out the query and use an online jsonpath page. can i do this query just using jsonpath? or do i have to use something else

any help appreciated ta
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```js
var input = [{
        "name": "noot",
        "things": [{
                "stuff": "a",
                "id": 1,
                "otherid": 11
            },
            {
                "stuff": "b",
                "id": 2,
                "otherid": 22
            },
            {
                "stuff": "c",
                "id": 3,
                "otherid": 33
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "doot",
        "things": [{
                "stuff": "a",
                "id": 1,
                "otherid": 111
            },
            {
                "stuff": "b",
                "id": 2,
                "otherid": 222
            },
            {
                "stuff": "c",
                "id": 3,
                "otherid": 333
            }
        ]
    }
]
for (var i in input) {
  console.log(input[i]["name"])
  for (var j in input[i]["things"]) {
    console.log(input[i]["things"][j]["otherid"])
  }
}
```

You iterate the first array to get `name` and `things`, then you iterate the second array in `things` to get `otherid`

Comment: Cheers, but I hadnt thought of using code as well, i was just thinking the query.. how do i run that without dev tool?. i have a list, i was gonna just work out the query and use an online jsonpath page. ill update the main question too..

Comment: what language is that? and can i run it somehow lol, sorry

Comment: @GPV It was JavaScript

Comment: @GPV I run it directly on browser's console